# osmdroid cache everything in current view

Tags: java, android, maps, osmdroid, offline-caching

I want to be able to look at an area of an osmdroid map, and cache everything I see (all zoom levels). This is done in OSMNavigator. I only want to use normal osmdroid (no bonus pack).
Any idea how I'd do this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the Cache Manager

Wiki article on the Cache Manager https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Cache-Manager

Source: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/tileprovider/cachemanager/CacheManager.java

Example usage: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/samplefragments/cache/SampleCacheDownloader.java

Basic workflow:

- Get the bounding box of the current view from the map
- Use the cache manager to start an async task to start the download for the bounding box for whatever zoom levels you want.
- As the download is progressing, update the ui to show progress (if you want)